# powershell script to copy uploaded json file and put in dynamodb table

Tags: powershell, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

I have uploaded my .json inside a folder in S3 bucket and now I want to put the same json inside a Dynamodb table. How can I achieve this using powershell?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you would read the object from S3 with [Read-S3Object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Read-S3Object.html):

```
# Downloads an S3 file locally
Read-S3Object -BucketName test-files -Key sample.txt -File local-sample.txt
# Import text as json
$json = Get-Content local-sample.txt | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
```

And the basic steps to submit to dynamoDB taken directly from the [AWS Powershell Code Samples](https://aws.amazon.com/developer/language/net/code-samples/powershell-code-samples/):

```
# Create an Amazon DynamoDB Document Model Table Object
# To create this client, we likely need an AWS Credential and AWS RegionEndpoint object

# You may be able to use default credentials, however in this exampe we will create a
# credential object to use.
$awsCredential = Get-AWSCredential -ProfileName profilename

# Create a RegionEndpoint object directly, or using an AWS Region name
$region = [Amazon.RegionEndpoint]::USWest2
$region = [Amazon.RegionEndpoint]::GetBySystemName('us-west-2')

# Create an AmazonDynamoDBClient. This is used for the underlying API calls
#   - Use default AWS credentials, or an AWS credential object
$client = New-Object -TypeName Amazon.DynamoDBv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient -ArgumentList $region
$client = New-Object -TypeName Amazon.DynamoDBv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient -ArgumentList $awsCredential, $region

# Create a Table object. This is used for calls using the DynamoDB Document Model
$table = [Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DocumentModel.Table]::LoadTable($client, $tableName)

# Create a doc from your json
$document = [Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DocumentModel.Document]::FromJson($json)
# Perform the PutItem operation.
$table.PutItem($document)
```